# How to set marker in google maps after button click?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to set a marker in google maps by giving the latitude and longitude of a certain place after finding places by using this:

```
  public void findPlace() {

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();

    try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .setFilter(typeFilter)
        .build(getActivity());

        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

        //to add marker for destination location


    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }
}
```

From this i get the place and i am using the following to get lat and long of the place searched:

```
 Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(MainActivity.this, data);
 Log.e("lat and long", place.getLatLng().latitude + place.getLatLng().longitude )
```

after this i am trying to set marker to that lat and long using this method i created :

```
 protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude) {

    Logger.e("inside" ,"create marker");
    return mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title("Destination")
            .snippet("Snippet Destination").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.black)));

}
```

and this method seems to work only inside onverride method onMapReady.

How can I use it after button click?

Answer (score 1):

Call below method when you want put marker on map.

```
public Marker placeMarker(EventInfo eventInfo) {
    Marker m  = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(eventInfo.getLatLong()).title(eventInfo.getName()));
    return m;

 }
```